# Plex on Ubuntu Server will not update metadata

Tags: server, permissions, metadata, plex

This is my first Ubuntu server so please use layman's terms.  I have Ubuntu server 14.04.4 and the Plex version 0.9.16.3.1840-cece46d.  So the plex server is working, I have added two movies and can play them.  The metadata for the movies in my library will not update.  All i can find on this is that it could be a permissions problem but I am not sure and don't know how to fix this if that is what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `/var/lib/plexmediaserver/` folder is owned by `Plex`.

```
sudo chown -R plex:plex /var/lib/plexmediaserver/
```

Hope this helps!